# Mysql left join, sum, and group_by

Tags: mysql, left-join

i've 4 tables. **region**, **land**, **house**, and **goods**.

- **land** have one-to-one rels. with **region**.
- **land** have one-to-many rels. with **house**.
- **house** have one-to-many rels. with **goods**.

[image: a busy cat]

**sqlfiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5eaec

**current query**:

```
SELECT
    Sum(land.wide) AS land_wide,
    Sum(house.price) AS house_price,
    Sum(goods.amount) AS goods_amount,
    Sum(goods.price) AS goods_price,
    region.region_name
FROM
    land
LEFT JOIN house ON house.land_id = land.id
LEFT JOIN goods ON goods.house_id = house.id
LEFT JOIN region ON land.region_id = region.id
GROUP BY
    region.region_name
ORDER BY
    region.id ASC
```

but not works as expected.

**desired output**:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| land_wide | house_price | goods_price | goods_amount | region  |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| 510       | 57910       | 1900        | 56           | Tokyo   |
|           |             |             |              | Osaka   |
|           |             |             |              | Nagoya  |
|           |             |             |              | Sapporo |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
```

Would someone kindly offer me a solution which would help? I am pretty sure it could be done in SQL?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to get the regions with highest house price?

Comment: @PseudoAj i'm trying to calculate(SUM) each elements based on region.

Comment: Wouldn't `Sapporo` have land_wide sum of 651?

Comment: @zedfoxus yes, `Sapporo` have land_wide 651 (only one land in `Sapporo`).

Comment: So if I understand it right you need `land_wide`,`house_price`, etc for each region i.e. each region will have a row in your output unlike the desired output you mentioned in above question?

Comment: @PseudoAj exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   land_wides.land_wide, 
   house_prices.house_price, 
   goods_amounts_prices.goods_price, 
   goods_amounts_prices.goods_amount, 
   region.region_name
FROM region
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
              Sum(land.wide) AS land_wide,
              region.id AS region_id
           FROM region
           LEFT JOIN land ON land.region_id = region.id
           GROUP BY region.id) land_wides ON region.id = land_wides.region_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
              Sum(house.price) AS house_price,
              region.id AS region_id
           FROM region
           LEFT JOIN land ON land.region_id = region.id
           LEFT JOIN house ON house.land_id = land.id
           GROUP BY region.id) house_prices ON region.id = house_prices.region_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
              Sum(goods.amount) AS goods_amount,
              Sum(goods.price) AS goods_price,
              region.id AS region_id
           FROM region
           LEFT JOIN land ON land.region_id = region.id
           LEFT JOIN house ON house.land_id = land.id
           LEFT JOIN goods ON goods.house_id = house.id
           GROUP BY region.id) goods_amounts_prices on goods_amounts_prices.region_id = region.id
ORDER BY region.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Left join should be inner join. You want to have grouping on matching rows. Not unmatched rows, hence grouping on sum.